# Why doesn't instanceof work with JPanel and JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I feel like I'm missing something blindingly obvious here, so low hanging fruit for a Java guru:

I have code that looks like this:

```
private static void myFunc(JComponent c) {
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            //stuff
        }
        else if (c instanceof JMenu) {
            // other stuff
        }
}
```

Even though JPanel and JMenu are both subclasses of JComponent, the first `instanceof` gives an error:

```
Incompatible conditional operand types JComponent and JPanel
```

While the second one works fine. Why does it think that my `JComponent` could never be a `JPanel`?

Comment: Are you importing `javax.swing.JPanel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're importing a different JPanel from somewhere. For the minute, try using the fully qualified types:

```
private static void myFunc(javax.swing.JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof javax.swing.JPanel) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Beyond that, I can't think of any reason it wouldn't compile... if you can come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would help. This compiles fine:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void myFunc(JComponent c) {
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed appear to be the case. Curious what other JPanel I could possibly be importing... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would double-check the imports.

Are you sure you've imported the very `JPanel` and the very `JComponent` class you wanted?
Are they the following?

```
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`if(javax.swing.JPanel.isInstance(c)){`

Comment: `.class`? But why would you do that?

Comment: Right, it should be `if(javax.swing.JPanel.class.isInstance(c)){`, and that sidesteps the import questions as well as being a bit faster than `instanceof` (a micro-optimization, but why not).

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Panel
{
  private static void myFunc(JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof JPanel) {
      //stuff
    } else if (c instanceof JMenu) {
      // other stuff
    }
  }
}
```